# What are the technical camera specs for the HTC Wildfire S?

Tags: metadata, focal-length, cameraphones, specification

I am trying to do some CGI manipulations on pictures I've taken. In order to fake reality with some 3D object inserted in the picture, I need some information to configure my virtual camera so it can match my real one.

The problem is that I'm using the camera of my Smartphone, which is a HTC Wildfire S. There are no specs concerning the camera in the manual nor on the Internet.

I need to find out the focal length and the width of CCD sensor (and maybe some other things I might be asked by the CGI software later on). Is there a good and simple way to find these?

Comment: If the EXIF contains both the FocalLength and FocalLengthIn35mmFilm, you can get the crop factor relative to 35mm film. Combined with the aspect ratio of the image, you should be able to get a good estimate of the sensor size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A search for HTC Wildfire specifications returns very little information about the camera, but searching for specific attributes like "aperture" and "focal length" yeilded some bits and pieces.  Wikipedia also had an article on sensor sizes (fourth reference below):

- Focal length: [3.5mm](http://www.flickr.com/photos/bestboyzde/5703371169/meta/)
- ISO: [75](http://www.flickr.com/photos/bestboyzde/5703371169/meta/)
- Aperture: [f/2.2](http://www.htcphones.net/htc-sensation-review/) ?
- Sensor is probably [1/6"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_sensor_format#Table_of_sensor_sizes)  2.4mm x 1.8mm
- Resolution: [2592x1944](http://www.thephonedatabase.com/HTC_Rhyme_771_vs_HTC_Wildfire_201_Compare_Phones)

Comment: Wow… Where did you find all that?

Comment: Searched on specific things like wildfire focal length, and pieced it together.

Comment: Helpful in the specific case but not in the general; maybe you could add your search approach to the answer?

Comment: Alternately, since this is accepted, maybe just change the question to "what are the technical camera specs for the HTC Wildfire S?"

Comment: Have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

It should add EXIF data to each photo taken. This contain much of the information you are asking for. You can get this by viewing the files on a PC or uploading to flickr. In [this example](http://www.flickr.com/photos/pixeled79/6507707953/meta/) the focal length and ISO are as follows however the iso does auto change dependant on conditions.

Focal Length    3.5 mm
ISO Speed   400

Flickr also holds profiles of each camera phone: [HTC Wildfire S](http://www.flickr.com/cameras/htc/wildfire_s_a510e/) wich lets you see others who